# Website allowing one to look up mathematicians, publications, and number of references for each paper

Tags: mathematics, website

I have been to such a website about a year ago when deciding which PhD program/advisor I wanted. I can't remember the name of the website! You could search someone's name and university etc. and it would pull up their publications, which journal they were in, and number of references that paper had in other papers.

I used it specifically for mathematics, although it could have been a more general data base (I can't remember).

Comment: You probably mean mathscinet. http://www.ams.org/mathscinet

Comment: Google Scholar, MathSciNet, and Thompson's Web of Science can all be used to do this.

Comment: MathSciNet is what mathematicians use.  If you are a student at a university with a research library, then you should have access to MathSciNet through that university's subscription.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe it was [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org/) (math-specific, partially free)?

Other possibilities (gathered from the comments to compile an answer) are [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), as well as [Mathscinet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/) (math-specific, non-free), [Scopus](http://scopus.com/) (non-free), [Web of Science](http://www.webofknowledge.com/) (non-free).

Comment: I did not use Zentralblatt for a long time, but tgey improved the presentation, the features and the search a lot and now I use it quite frequently.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I do like Zentralblatt! It seems as though it was mathscinet I was using, although I can't be sure. This works perfectly fine though!